# How do I import an image in my Stencil component?

Tags: stenciljs

I have my image uploaded in `../../../public-storybook/images/navbar/`, but I can't reference it inside my component!

I tried with `getAssetPath`, and still not working!

`private defaultProfileImage: string = getAssetPath('../../../public-storybook/images/navbar/default_image.png');` = not working.

`@State() defaultProfileImage: string = '../../../public-storybook/images/navbar/default_image.png'` = not working.

`<img src={/public-storybook/images/navbar/default_image.png} />` = not working!

Comment: can you define not working?

Comment: The image is not showing. I get status 404. I also noticed the type shows as text/plain, not sure if that's related.

Comment: `GET http://localhost:3333/public-storybook/images/navbar/default_image.png 404 (Not Found)`

Comment: Is that image available on the server independently of Stencil at `http://localhost:3333/public-storybook/images/navbar/default_image.png`? This would help differentiate between the image not being available at all or Stencil's not being able to resolve the image based on the provided path (https://stenciljs.com/docs/assets#resolution-overview)